# QCustomPlot QCPItemEllipse position

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I have a QCustomPlot Graph with the center (0,0) i want to add an ellipse item around all the data on the graph but there i am only able to set the top left and bottom right positions of the ellipse, this shows almost in the center of the graph but its a bit off because im not able to set the center off the ellipse as center isnt a position its an anchor

does anyone know how i would be able to set the center of my ellipse item to (0,0)?

```
    QCPItemEllipse *ellipse = new QCPItemEllipse(ui->customPlot);
    ellipse->setAntialiased(true);
    ellipse->topLeft->setCoords(lowestX, highestY);
    ellipse->bottomRight->setCoords(highestX, lowestY);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man, the position of ellipse's center is determined by it's top-left and bottom-right points.

E.g. `center.x == (topLeft.x + bottomRight.x)/2` and `center.y == (topLeft.y + bottomRight.y)/2`. That's how ellipses work in math :).

In your code, center will be in (0,0) if `(lowestX + hightX) == 0` & `(lowestY + hightY) == 0`.

Or maybe I'm not getting what are you talking about?

If you want to move center of ellipse in easy way, you can create class derived from `QCPItemEllipse` with field `QCPItemTracer *mCenterTracer` and with following stuff in constructor:

```
mCenterTracer->setStyle(QCPItemTracer::tsNone);

topLeft->setParentAnchor(mCenterTracer->position);
bottomRight->setParentAnchor(mCenterTracer->position);

topLeft->setCoords(-xRadius/2.0, -yRadius/2.0);
bottomRight->setCoords(xRadius/2.0, yRadius/2.0);
```

So method for moving center (without changing radiuses) will look like:

```
void FreakingEllipse::moveCenter(double x, double y) {
    mCenterTracer->position->setCoords(x, y);
}
```

*By the way, you can add following if you want your ellipse to have constant radius in pixels, while it's center is still stick to plot coordinates:*

```
topLeft->setType(QCPItemPosition::ptAbsolute);
bottomRight->setType(QCPItemPosition::ptAbsolute);
```